# Preparing and executing MySQL SELECT query from parameters

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to make a function for Select statements. It will give result based from the parameters passed. I tried using it and it gives the results I am expecting.

I know that it is still unpolished but I would like to know what are the critical things in it that should be fixed or improved so that it would be ready for usage.

Below is the parameter passed:

```
 $parameters = array(
    'select' => 'user_id, username, password',
    'type' => 'i',
    'from' => 'users',
    'where_column' => 'user_id',
    'where_row' => '4'
);
```

And here is the function:

```
function select_query($parameter){
    require('database.php');

    $select = $parameter['select'];
    $type = $parameter['type'];
    $from = $parameter['from'];

    $columns = '';
    $column_array = explode(', ', $select);
    foreach ($column_array as $value) {
        $columns .= '$'. $value .', ';
    }

    //prepares the WHERE section of the SQL statement if the WHERE parameter exist
    $where = '';
    $wc = '';
    $wr = '';

    if(isset($parameter['where_column']) && isset($parameter['where_row'])){
        $wc = $parameter['where_column'];
        $wr = $parameter['where_row'];          

        $where = " WHERE $wc = ?"; 
    }

    /* create a prepared statement */
    if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT $select FROM $from". $where)) {

        if($where != ''){
            /* bind parameters for markers */
            $stmt->bind_param($type, $wr);
        }

        /* execute query *Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. * */
        $stmt->execute();

        /* bind result variables *Returns a resultset or FALSE on failure.* */          
        $res = $stmt->get_result();

        /* fetch value */
        if($res->num_rows > 0){
            while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){ // fetch_assoc *returns NULL if there are no more rows in resultset.*
                $results[] = $row;
            }
            return $results;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

        /* close statement */
        $stmt->close();
    }

    /* close connection */
    $conn->close();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right off the bat, there are a couple of things about your code that make me feel uneasy. I'll start by running through your code, almost line by line, explaining what I feel could be done to improve on what you have right now:

```
function select_query($parameter){
    require('database.php');

    $select = $parameter['select'];
    $type = $parameter['type'];
    $from = $parameter['from'];
```

For starters, you declare a function, that takes just one single argument. What type the function expects is an unknown, unless you actually bother to check the code of the function itself. `$parameter` (not the best name for the argument, IMHO), is expected to be an array, so your function signature should reflect that:

```
function selectQuery(array $parameter)
{
}
```

That would tell anyone who wants to use your function that they need to pass an array, not a string or object. If they pass anything else, they'll get a fatal error.

Next up, your function starts by `require`-ing a file. Not `require_once`, or checking if the file has already been processed by PHP, it just requires it. The result will probably be a lot of disk IO (which is bad for performance), and a function with an external dependency. Suppose someone opened the database.php file, and decided to change a thing or two. The variables declared within that file might change names, and you're left with a function that doesn't work anymore, for no apparent reason. To me, it seems like all you really need from that database.php file, is a `mysqli` connection object (or PDO, but since you've tagged your question `mysqli`, I'm assuming that that's what `$conn` is).

A far more common (and all-round better) way to obtain a DB connection would be to have the caller pass the connection **of their choice** to your function, again, as an argument. Here, you can use type-hints, too, to ensure the argument is indeed a `mysqli` instance/resource:

```
function selectQuery(mysqli $conn, array $parameter)
{}
```

That way, the caller can choose what DB should be used to query, what user, and -crucially- the caller can decide to re-use the connection for other tasks (other queries), and your function is no longer responsable for closing the connection, that falls to the caller.

The last thing about this piece of code that I'd change is this:

```
    $select = $parameter['select'];
    $type = $parameter['type'];
    $from = $parameter['from'];
```

Yes, using type-hints, you can ensure that the caller can only pass an array to your function, but an array is actually a rather vague thing, especially in PHP. Consider this:

```
function needsArray(array $argument)
{
    return $argument['total'] - $argument['costs'];
}
```

Now, these attempts at calling this function will fail:

```
needsArray(123);
needsArray(null);
needsArray('string');
needsArray(new stdClass);
```

But these are, going by the signature, correct invocations of the function:

```
needsArray([]);
needsArray((array) new stdClass);
needsArray(['total' => 'some string', 'costs']);
needsArray(['total' => 123456, 'costs' => 60]);
```

Yet, only the last call is actually valid, the others will emit notices (undefined index), or won't do anything even remotely meaningful.
At the very least, you'll have to check for every expected key in the `$parameter` array using `isset` or `array_key_exists`, and then you'll still have to ensure that the value of each key is what you expect it to be. That's going to add a lot of silly-looking `if`'s and `else`'s to the code. What's more: if one of the keys doesn't exist, or doesn't contain the type of data you expect it to contain, what do you do? You'll probably have to throw an exception. Let's take our dummy `needsArray` function, and re-write it in a safe way. Note that we're only expecting a 1D array, with just 2 keys, but just look at the amount of added code we need to add to ensure the array looks the part:

```
function needsArray(array $argument)
{
    if (!isset($argument['total']) || !is_numeric($argument['total'])) 
    {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(
            sprintf(
                '%s expects array argument with key "total" set to a numeric value'
                __FUNCTION__
            )
        );
    }
    if (!isset($argument['costs']) || !is_numeric($argument['costs'])) 
    {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(
            sprintf(
                '%s expects array argument with key "costs" set to a numeric value'
                __FUNCTION__
            )
        );
    }
    return $argument['total'] - $argument['costs'];
}
```

That's just an awful lot of clutter. Especially if you consider the fact that it's more than likely that the array you're passing to this function will be passed to several other functions, each of which might perform the same checks over and over.

## TL;TR

If your function requires something (like a DB connection), don't have your function literally `require` a file to resolve its dependencies: force the caller to supply it by means of arguments.

If you need complex arguments, like your `$parameter` argument, either split that argument up into hintable, simple arguments:

```
function selectQuery(mysqli $conn, array $select, $from, ...)
```

Or create a *class*. The getters can validate the data, and you can write the setters to return the data in whatever format you like. Then, just type-hint that class where you need it:

```
class SelectParam
{
    protected $select = ['*'];//default value
    public function setSelect(array $select)
    {
        $this->select = $select;
        return $this;
    }
    public function getSelect($asString = false)
    {
        $select = $this->select;
        if ($asString)
            $select = implode(', ', $select);
        return $select;
    }
}
function selectQuery(mysqli $conn, SelectParam $param)
{}
```

Other issues have been covered by other answers. Issues like

- Unused vars: `$columns` -> it's never used, and what it contains just doesn't seem to make much sense, IMHO
- Weird variable names: `$wr`, `$wc` are meaningless. It's only because of the context in which they are used that we can deduce `wr` means *"whereRow"*. But if the code gets any bigger, and I have to start scrolling to where the vars are first used to figure out what they actually are, that maintaining the code will be a pain. Even if the maintainer is the one who wrote the code in the first place
- Lack of comments. Yes, I've not commented my code snippets here to save space, but if you haven't added the actual comments in your real-life code either, you should do so ASAP. Any half-decent API uses the doc-blocks of functions/methods for auto-completion and provides you with information about the method you're calling:

  /**

  - Executes a SELECT query on the connection, returns the results as an array of assoc arrays
  - @param mysqli $conn
  - @param SelectParam $param
  - @return array
    */
    function selectQuery(mysqli $conn, SelectParam $param)
    {}

With that doc-block, an editor like PHPStorm will display the description text when you've typed `selectQuery`, and it'll notify the developer if any of the arguments you're passing is of an incompatible type:

```
$conn = new PDO();
selectQuery($conn, 123);//PHPStorm will pick up on the wrong types
```

These kinds of features IDE's have can, and often do, significantly reduce the time spent debugging, and prevent countless bugs from ever being committed in the first place.

Comment: +1, but I think you should specify that you are talking about function-level comments, not comments inside the code (because the OP has those, they are just not all that helpful).

Answer (score 3):

- **Class vs Function**: Personally, I don't like using an array as parameter like this, I would transform the whole thing into a class (and then have methods such as `setSelect`, `setType`, etc). It does add a bit of code overhead, but it is easier to document and a lot easier to understand how to use it. With arrays, you need really good documentation, otherwise everyone using your function must look into the actual code.
- **Documentation**: I would add a PHPDoc comment to the function, documenting which values can safely be user input and which ones can't be, what will be returned, and what happens on errors.
- **Comments**: most of your comments aren't really necessary, as they just repeat what the code says. Comments like these actually make your code harder to read, as a reader has to skip over them, and also because a reader will ignore all comments after a while, even the ones that actually are important.
- **Naming**: I would name `where_row` `where_name` or similar, it seems clearer (but if you do change this to a class, a function such as `where($column, $value)` would be a lot clearer than two separate values).
- **Naming**: Don't shorten variable names. It's hard to guess what `wc` and `wr` mean. Even when I have figured it out, I have to make that mapping from `wc` to `whereColumn` each time I see the variable (I'm not saying that it's a lot of extra work for the reader, but it is some, and it can be avoided).
- **Error Handling**: Your comments state that some database commands return false on failure, but you don't handle that at all. It would make finding future bugs in your code easier if you threw an exception or at least returned false.
- **Unnecessary Variables**: You don't really need `$wc` as variable. It's only ever used in one place, so you can just use the array value there directly.
- **Unnecessary Code**: You need four rows to calculate `$columns`, but it's never used anywhere.
- **Code Structure**: I think how you handle the optional `$where` part could be improved. Currently, it needs to be checked in two different places, which leads to confusing code. I think it's worth having a little duplication to increase code clarity:

  ```
      if(isset($parameter['where_column']) && isset($parameter['where_row'])){
          $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT $select FROM $from WHERE $parameter['where_column'] = ?");
          $stmt->bind_param($type, $parameter['where_row']);
      } else {
          $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT $select FROM $from");
      }
      $stmt->execute();
      [...]
  ```

Answer (score 3):

`$conn-close()` is a problem in two ways:

- Where is `$conn` opened in the first place?  My guess is that it was done within `database.php` as a side-effect.  Such side-effects are deceptive.  It would less mysterious for `database.php` to define a `connect()` function.

  ```
  require('database.php');

  function select_query($parameters) {
      $conn = connect();
      …
  }
  ```
- You shouldn't just open and close connections casually, because opening connections has a large overhead.  Your application should try to reuse existing connections for as many queries as possible.  The connection should be passed to the `select_query` function.  Alternatively, if you keep the code as it is, be sure to use [persistent connections](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php).